# Why does not work jquery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have form with one field, and I validating this field by means of `jquery validation`. But my form sand in all case but in `js` I inject constrains, validation does't work.

Help me fix this issue. Thank You.

This is `form` in `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <title>Form</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-x-1 p-y-3">
        <form id="form" class="card card-block m-x-auto bg-faded form-width" method="POST" action="go" name="validation">
            <legend class="m-b-1 text-xs-center">Enter data</legend>

            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="has-float-label">
                <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="text-xs-center">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Edit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is `js` script for validation:

```
$(function() {
  // Form contain attribute name="registration".
  $("form[name='validation']").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },

    // Error message.
    messages: {
      name: "Error"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

I have `jquery-validation` library in same folder what `index.html`. 
[image]

Comment: your jquery min js should be always on the top of all other js move this    `<script src="src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js"></script>` to top of all js

Comment: if you want run the jquery plugin means you need to include the jquey first then jquery plugin . @pavul

Comment: My two cents: is this `src=` a typo? 
`src="src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code import css and js in this order

```
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
```

but you should import jquery first and then it's extentions i.e. , jquery validation. I would also recommend using jquery before importing bootstrap component file, to be on the safer side. So, Your correct order of import will be :-

```
    <script src="src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
```

Although, this is out of context but ,you should import your custom css after the bootstrap css file.

Comment: this is don't stop sending empty form, may be I have more mistakes? When I click on button then browser send me to `action="go"` add _/go_ to path. But idea validation: If form is empty or name length less 5 symbol `name: {required: true, minlength: 5 }` then I stay on same page and get messages: `{name: "Error"}`. Why isn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Please swap both the scripts like given below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

When you use jQuery plugins, It always requires jQuery. In your case you have added validation library first and then jQuery, hence it's not worked.

Comment: There is a typo too: `src="src="//`.

Comment: Yup, Just I have changed.

Comment: @Shyam Shingadiya my import:  `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min‌​.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="validation.js"></script>` same result, don't work. may be there are still errors?

Comment: Can you please check your console and share errors.